# Is there a way to avoid UNIONS in SQL to INSERT multiple tables into one larger table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 12 tables, each representing data for a different month. I am trying to combine these tables into one larger table. So far I have created a new table with the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `data_base.data_set.new_data_table`
(
    ride_id STRING, 
    rideable_type STRING, 
    started_at TIMESTAMP, 
    ended_at TIMESTAMP, 
    start_lat FLOAT64, 
    start_lng FLOAT64, 
    end_lat FLOAT64, 
    end_lng FLOAT64, 
    member_casual STRING, 
    start_station_name STRING, 
    end_station_name STRING
);
```

Then I wrote the following to insert the first of my tables into the newly created table:

```
INSERT INTO `data_base.data_set.new_data_table` 
  (ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual, start_station_name, end_station_name) 

(SELECT ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual, start_station_name, end_station_name 
FROM 
  `data_base.data_set.tab_2021-09`)
```

I now wish to repeat this INSERT INTO process for tab_2021-10, tab_2021-11,...,tab_2022-07. Is there a way to avoid writing out the SELECT and FROM statements repeatedly with UNIONS for each new table? I.e. a way to iterate the SELECT and FROM statements through all 12 tables?

Comment: use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` - see [Wildcard table syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#wildcard_table_syntax) for details

Comment: Why do you have different tables for each month?

Answer (score 0):

Posting @MikhailBerlyant's comment as community wiki answer.

You may use [WILDCARD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#wildcard_table_syntax) to iterate `INSERT` over multiple tables based on your **table suffix** which in your case would be **2021-10**, **2021-11**, **2022-07** because `tab_` is your consistent prefix. Therefore you may use below query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `data_base.data_set.new_data_table` 
  (ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual, start_station_name, end_station_name) 

(SELECT ride_id, rideable_type, started_at, ended_at, start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng, member_casual, start_station_name, end_station_name 
FROM 
  `data_base.data_set.tab_*`)
```

If you have conflicts in using the **tab_*** as your wildcard, you may alter the above query and use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` (if necessary) to have a condition on your wildcard to satisfy your final query.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for improvements